# How to check closest checkbox using jQuery

Tags: php, checkbox, find, closest

I have an foreach loop. In the foreach loop I have following code.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <img alt="" class=" center-block developerlocationselection check" style="width:35%; margin-top:10%;" src="../../css/collecting/route-select.png">

    <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" class="developernames" name="developernames">

</div>
```

I have an image and checkbox.

What i want to do is when i click the image, the closest checkbox to the image become checked.

**This is my Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    //$(".developerlocationselection").on('click', function () {
    $(".developerlocationselection").click( function () {
        alert(2);
        $(this).closest().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
</script>
```

How I can check the closest checkbox on click of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the **supplied selector**. You need to use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) or [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$(this).next('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

or even

```
$(this).next().prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @Gergely Bakos

Answer (score 0):

The below statements check the relevant checkbox.

Try:

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Or

```
$(this).next('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```